# C -- Structs and Pointers Basic Questions

Tags: c, struct

So I'm trying to learn C right now, and I have some basic struct questions I'd like to clear up:

Basically, everything centers around this snippet of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX_NAME_LEN 127

typedef struct {
    char name[MAX_NAME_LEN + 1];
    unsigned long sid;
} Student;

/* return the name of student s */
const char* getName (const Student* s) { // the parameter 's' is a pointer to a Student struct
    return s->name; // returns the 'name' member of a Student struct
}

/* set the name of student s
If name is too long, cut off characters after the maximum number of characters allowed.
*/
void setName(Student* s, const char* name) { // 's' is a pointer to a Student struct |     'name' is a pointer to the first element of a char array (repres. a string)
    char temp;
int i;
for (i = 0, temp = &name; temp != '\0'; temp++, i++) {
    *((s->name) + i) = temp;
}

/* return the SID of student s */
unsigned long getStudentID(const Student* s) { // 's' is a pointer to a Student struct
    return s->sid;
}

/* set the SID of student s */
void setStudentID(Student* s, unsigned long sid) { // 's' is a pointer to a Student struct | 'sid' is a 'long' representing the desired SID
    s->sid = sid;
}
```

I've commented up the code in an attempt to solidify my understanding of pointers; I hope they're all accurate.

Also, I have another method,

```
Student* makeAndrew(void) {
    Student s;
    setName(&s, "Andrew");
    setStudentID(&s, 12345678);
    return &s;
}
```

which I'm sure is wrong in some way... I also think my setName is implemented incorrectly.

Any pointers? (no pun intended)

Comment: Instead of copying manually, use e.g. `strcpy`.

Comment: `setName` doesn't check for input string length, so it may crash for the long enough input string. you need `temp != '\0' && i < MAX_NAME_LEN` at your `for` loop there.

Answer (score 3):

This is very wrong. If you insist on not using `strcpy` do something like this (not tested)

```
int iStringLength = strlen(name);
for (i = 0; i < iStringLength; i++) {
    s->name[i] = name[i];
}
```

but make sure that the length is not longer than your array size.

This is also wrong

```
Student* makeAndrew(void) {
   Student s;
   setName(&s, "Andrew");
   setStudentID(&s, 12345678);
   return &s; 
}
```

because the `s` object is destroyed when the function exits - it is local to the function scope and yet you return a pointer to it. So if you try to access the struct using this pointer it will not be valid as the instance no longer exists. If you want to do this you should dynamically allocate it using `malloc` . Alternatively do not return a pointer at all and use the alternative option of @Andrew .

Comment: Down-votes at the ready chaps and chapesses, but please do not encourage a new C user to use malloc() - there are soooo many reasons why it is borked that we really should discourage its use!  At least until they are aware of the pitfalls

Comment: @Andrew, that's a silly thing to say: how else does one get dynamically allocated memory?

Comment: OK, I'm coming from a safety critical environment, and I guess the issues are slightly less worrisome in the desk-top world, but my answer is: DON'T!

I can expand, but it's heading OT the question :)

Comment: @MM - GPWM... I'm new around here :)

Comment: I think you're right - it should be clarified that it's more error prone and easy to cause memory leaks using it, but on the other side, you can't really learn and understood C without seeing for yourself how scopes and pointers work, right? ;).

Comment: Thanks. Will 's->name[i] = name[i];' work, given that the type of 'name' in setName is 'const char* name'? Namely, will it still be able to index into name, eg. name[i]?

Comment: @Ryan - I suggest he uses strncpy() - note not strcpy() which could cause buffer overflow if the input string is too long.

Comment: The copying is one off, you don't copy the terminating `'\0'`.

Answer (score 2):

In your "another method" you are locally declaring `Student s`, which will dynamically allocate space (usually on the stack) and you are returning that address on completion.

However, that stack-space will be released on the return, so there is no guarantee that the data is uncorrupted - in fact the likelyhood is that it will be!

Declare `Student s` in the call to your method, and pass the pointer to makeAndrew:

```
void makeAndrew(Student *s) {
    setName( s, "Andrew");
    setStudentID( s, 12345678);
}


...

Student s;
makeAndrew( &s );

...
```

Comment: just to make things clear, the `return` statement in your `makeAndrew` implementation is trying to return a double pointer and is not required.

Comment: Thanks @Deepanjan - copy/paste error of the original now corrected

Answer (score 0):

Your function `makeAndrew` returns pointer to a local variable. It is only valid before the scope ends, so as soon as the function finishes, it will change when the memory gets overwritten - i. e. almost instantly. You would have to allocate it dynamically (using `Student *s = new Student;`, or if you really want to stick to pure C, `Student *s = malloc (sizeof Student );`, and then free it outside the function after it is not needed to avoid memory leak.

Or do it as Andrew suggested, it's less error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

I would change the makeAndrew() function to just return a struct, not a pointer to a struct to correct the error with respect to returning a pointer to a temporary variable:

```
Student makeAndrew(void) 
{
    Student s;
    setName(&s, "Andrew");
    setStudentID(&s, 12345678);
    return s;
}

Student aStudent = makeAndrew();
```

Your setName does have an error with respect to temp, which should be a char *, since you are incrementing it in your loop to point to another character in the input c-string. I think it was missing the null termination as well. And as you mention in your comment, there should be a check for overflow of the name char array in Student:

```
void setName(Student* s, const char* name) { // 's' is a pointer to a Student struct |     
    // 'name' is a pointer to the first element of a char array (repres. a string)
    const char *temp;
    int i;
    for (i = 0, temp = name; *temp != '\0' && i <= MAX_NAME_LEN; temp++, i++) 
    {
       *((s->name) + i) = *temp;
    }
    s->name[i] = '\0';
}
```

You can use strncpy to simplify setName:

```
void setName2(Student *s,const char *name)
{
    #include <string.h>
    strncpy(s->name, name,MAX_NAME_LEN);
    s->name[MAX_NAME_LEN] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: I'll reserve the down-vote, but I'm curious to understand your reasoning for this, as this approach adds unnecessary overhead - although optimisation may well result in a pointer being passed anyway?

Comment: @Andrew Which function are you referring to?

Comment: I was referring to the comment `to just return a struct, not a pointer to a struct`

Comment: @Andrew The poster said they are trying to learn C and understand structs and was returning a pointer to a local variable. I think  malloc() is a lesson or two down the road.  But they provided a prototype of "* makeAndrew(void)" which implies a malloc(). The closest alternative is to change the return type to a copy of a struct. Until they learn malloc I consider it necessary overhead to do a "make..." function (versus a set...(struct *) or initialize(struct *) function.

Comment: I see your point, but I still suggest the most-correct answer is to declare the structure outside the function, and pass the pointer in (see my answer, and others). But your way works...